# Can't ping router after assigning an IP to tap

Tags: networking, router

I created a tap interface and added an IP using...

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap tap0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.0.210/24 dev tap0
sudo ip link set dev tap0 up
```

Beforehand I was able to ping my router at 192.168.0.1 . Now by pinging I get a `Destination host unreachable` error. Checking my router I discovered I also can't load the router's webpage.

Before:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         kabelbox.local  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

After:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         kabelbox.local  0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 tap0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tap0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

What's wrong here? I just can't get this working any way. After deleting tap0 everything works fine again

Answer (score 0):

just in case some other noob like me will encounter this and is not finding anything appropriate.
The metric of the tap device was set by default to 0, so tap0 has a higher priority and so the system is choosing it over wlp3s0 for different tasks.
it seems to be ping for sure, something used to connect to my router and its not affecting internet connectivity because traffic is being routed through
wlp3s0 (see routing table)